# How could you escape the universe entirely or reach higher dimensions

Tags: space, time

Given a multiverse that exists as a projection/hologram/simulation of a super sentience, how could a character in a type 3 (or 4) society that exists in apparent 3 dimensions of space and 1 of time (like ours) actually leave the universe entirely.

Context and suppositions.
The universe in question exists within an infinite multiverse and also has a mirror universe, that at the moment of its inception created a mirror universe where time flows in the opposite direction.  This universe is a closed system.  It began with a big bang.  Distance and time between all universes in this multiverse is irrelevant, since each universe exists at a different plane; essentially the super sentience either IS or exists in dimensions unfathomable or incomprehensible to anything existing.  In plain English, I am using our current time space continuum and universe as a template, and want to know a way that you could literally break a hole in reality to escape to those unfathomable dimensions.

EDIT: to specify, I'm seeking plausible ideas from cosmology and theoretical physics that could potentially cause an apocalyptic event in another part of the universe, say a neighboring galaxy, that could change the laws of physics. (E.G.  creating a white hole, quantum tunneling a Higgs boson from false vacuum to true vacuum and thus causing vacuum decay)   I planned on doing this by "breaking a hole in reality" with this literary mechanism to change the laws of physics

Comment: To my humble understanding, the universe contains everything. If you decide that there is something outside in your world, it's entirely up to you. You decide what's there and how to get there. There are no valid scientific explanations.

Comment: There must be some rules describing how reality behaves. If you can break out of your universe then the real rules are those of the multiverse. In the same way that there are different gravities on different planets, but all planets and travel between them is described by the laws of gravitation.

Answer (score 2):

**How to Break a Hole in Reality: However you want to**

There is no known way to science by which one might break a hole in reality, nor will there likely be one discovered within any of our lifetimes (and, quite possibly, there might never be one discovered).

Because of this, you, as the author, have freedom to come up with any method you want that will tear a hole in reality. It is your own physics in your own universe, which is only similar to ours, and isn't necessarily the same as ours.

If, however, you want a way to do this which would work in real life, then no one can help you. Even thoughts about the existence of a multiverse aren't anything more than random, baseless speculation.

Comment: Agreed. Selling the plausibility to the reader is the test of a good writer.

Comment: thank you.  Without delving too deeply into the story, and focusing on the world I am creating: I am using our universe as the setting.  One in which a character from the mirroring universe where time is moving backward (entropy is decreasing), comes to our past from our future and will unwittingly influence a protagonist causing him to become a sort of Lovecraftian Eldritch Abomination that will find a way to in a limited capacity change or tweak the laws of physics.  Just looking for inspiration from theoretical physics and cosmology